# Custom Log in to facebook in ios application

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using the latest facebook sdk to integrate photo sharing in my iOS app. Currently working with iOS 5.0. I am able to login and share photos.

But for login, i have to use the `FBLoginView`. What I want to so is to call the methods from my own UIButton. Now, to find the `UIButton` associated with the `FBLoginView` i use [How to customize FBLoginVIew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280850/how-to-customize-fbloginview)

I can also find all the selectors associated with the button using actions `actionsForTarget:forControlEvent:`  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW6

But for calling this method I need to know which object is the login message sent to? How can I find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `sendActionsForControlEvents:` I just sent this message to the UIButton for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and it called the corresponding method(s). (but it is not working as I wanted.)

Comment: The FBLoginView button action could be tied to `UIControlEventTouchDownInside`.

Comment: no it is working with touchup inside. But the problem is with logout. It presents an action sheet, which opens up in portrait mode instead of landscape, and that too starting somewhere from the middle of the screen, such that logout button goes out of bounds.