# iOS Facebook SDK localization

Tags: ios, facebook, localization

I am trying to change text in `FBLoginView` button but I have no luck so far. I've tried to read **README** from `FacebookSDK` and look at internet. I added 2 languages in project Localizations sections it creates 2 files in Supporting files for each language but I tried to change strings in there with example content of **README** (with changed string values) but even if I changed english file I always get default login string.
Then I tried to add some Bundle settings and change some files in there but with no luck too. Can someone tell me how can I achieve change **facebook** strings step by step? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Update:*

*The method described here is no longer applicable for the latest Facebook SDKs. So please refer to the answers given by @Erik van der Neut or @Ted, and use the bundle [FacebookSDKStrings.bundle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle/Resources) that ships with the SDK for string overrides.*

---

The only way I found so far to localize/change the Facebook strings is described in their FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/

What I did was to copy the file `FacebookSDKOverrides.bundle` from the Scrumptious sample project that ships with the Facebook SDK. This is basically just a package that contains (can contain) different localization folders. If you want to add German strings, create a folder `de.lproj` within the bundle. This folder should contain a file `Localizable.strings`.

You can find a list of all overrideable strings in the file `FacebookSDKResources.bundle.README`. You can find it in the FacebookSDK folder:

```
FacebookSDK.framework/Resources/
```

or here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FacebookSDKResources.bundle.README

To add a German translation of the text of the login button, for example, you have to add the following to the file Localizable.strings in de.lproj:

```
"FBLV:LogInButton" = "Einloggen";
```

As a last step, you have to make sure that Facebook knows about the bundle. Therefore, you can add the following to your Info.plist:

```
<key>FacebookBundleName</key>
<string>FacebookSDKOverrides</string>
```

Alternatively, you can also specify this in code if you want to:

```
[FBSettings setResourceBundleName:@"FacebookSDKOverrides"];
```

This worked for me, although I would like to use my main bundle for overrides and just specify them in my normal app translations. This would come in more handy for the connection to translation tools as you don't need to translate multiple files per language.

Comment: For the latest Fb SDK the Fb message keys are completely different. For details see the other answer I just posted.

Answer (score 4):

As of Facebook SDK **4.9**

If you have downloaded the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios), theres a bundle named "**FacebookSDKStrings.bundle**"

1. add [FacebookSDKStrings.bundle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/FacebookSDKStrings.bundle/Resources) to your project
2. make sure you [enable Base Internalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW4) as described in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Make sure you're using the last version of the SDK. I was having a problem with the Localization for "Continue with Facebook" button. This was fixed on 4.24.0 as you can see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4x#4_24_0

Answer (score 3):

*As an update to the accepted answer here from Flo:*

For the latest Facebook SDK, the set of Facebook messages (and their identifying keys) has completely changed. For example, the "FBLV:LogInButton" key is no longer valid in the latest Fb SDK.

Because of this my Facebook strings were no longer getting localized, until I realized this and replaced all my Facebook messages with the latest `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` (v4.2) from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk -- I simply removed my original `FacebookSDKOverrides.bundle` and included this whole bundle `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` as is in my project (including the Resources sub folder in there), updated my project .plist files to point to it, and with that all the Facebook strings got localized again.

For example, the message for the default Login button label now looks like this:

```
/* The long label for the FBSDKLoginButton when the user is currently logged out */
"LoginButton.LogInLong" = "Log in with Facebook";
```

Luckily, Facebook's GitHub page now includes translations for these messages for lots of languages already (which in my case meant I no longer needed to run these past my translators).

Comment: what do you mean by `updated my project .plist files to point to it`?

Answer (score 0):

I just copied all string from "FacebookSDK.strings" from folder of langauge you want like  fr.lproj to my poject Localizable.strings (French) ...This way worked for me...