# Change text of FBLikeControl.h

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, facebook-like

Is it possible to change FBLikeControl "Like" label?

I searched on Facebook documentation and googled it but nothing found. =/
And setting the objectID with "?locale=ll_CC" seems not to work either.

I'm using iOS SDK v3.19.
Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following approach? It explains how to localize the images and strings used in the iOS SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/#localize

See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22783512/561485

Does that help you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It seems that the text label "Like" is hardcoded into the Facebook framework. =O
The images in the bundle folder are only for the login window.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up to use a custom image, the same way you would for `FBLoginView`.

```
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(320/2 - 93/2, self.view.frame.size.height -200, 93, 93);

for (id loginObject in loginView.subviews)
{
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
        UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_HERE"];
        loginButton.alpha = 0.7;
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [loginButton sizeToFit];
    }
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
        loginLabel.text = @"";
        loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```