# Know when facebook login button is pressed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to show a HUD when somebody press the facebook login button. Currently I struggle to know when the button was pressed.

I tried to grab all taps of the view, but this does not work for any reson on the facebook button...

**How can know when the facebook login is pressed, to call my HUD?**

Additional it would be nice to know which function the facebook login button triggers. Could not find out..

#### Code to grab taps, in LoginViewController.m (UPDATED, working solution)

```c
// workaround to find out when user tapped the login button
-(void)addTapFinder {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];

    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapped.delegate = self;
    tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    FBLoginView *fbButton = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    UIView * fbView = (UIView *)fbButton;
    fbView = [self.view viewWithTag:fbloginViewTAG];

    [fbView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

    DLog(@"found View %@", fbView);
}


-(void)tapped {
    DLog(@"tapped");
}
```

#### Debugger log

```c
[872:60b] -[LoginViewController FacebookLogin] [Line 283] loginview subviews: <FBShadowLabel: 0x16d17840; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (33 -1; 168 46); text = 'Connect  Facebook'; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x18136240>>
[872:60b] -[LoginViewController showFBLogin] [Line 231] show login View
[872:60b] -[LoginViewController tapped] [Line 250] tapped   // tapped somewhere in self.view, but not the login button
// tapped the login button, no "tapped" entry in the logfile
```

Below the complete code:

#### LoginViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "WebApi.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

-(IBAction)toSurroundView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) WebApi *swebapi;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstFBLoginDone;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *loginView;

@end
```

#### LoginViewController.m

```c
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()
@end

@implementation LoginViewController


static int const fbloginViewTAG = 203;

-(void)vinit {
    self.swebapi = [[WebApi alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"didRegisterUser" object:nil ];
    self.isFirstFBLoginDone = FALSE;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self vinit];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self showFBLogin];
}


-(void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)message {
    if ([[message name] isEqualToString:@"didRegisterUser"]) {
        [self toSurroundView];
    }
}

-(IBAction)toSurroundView {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; // connecting to Facebook, this is called to late!

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *surroundViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    surroundViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:surroundViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Facebook Things

-(void)showFBLogin {
    UIView *connectView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:connectView];
    [self FacebookLogin];   
    [self addTapFinder]; 
    DLog(@"show login View");
}

// workaround to find out when user tapped the login button
-(void)addTapFinder {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];

    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapped.delegate = self;
    tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    FBLoginView *fbButton = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    UIView * fbView = (UIView *)fbButton;
    fbView = [self.view viewWithTag:fbloginViewTAG];

    [fbView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];

    DLog(@"found View %@", fbView);
}

-(void)tapped {
    DLog(@"tapped");
}

-(void)FacebookLogin {

    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-ui-control/
    // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/session/

    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginView.delegate = self;
    loginView.tag = fbloginViewTAG;
    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"basic_info"];
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame,
                                   (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)),
                                   ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 80));

    // change fb login button text
    UILabel *fblabel = [loginView subviews][1];
    fblabel.text = @"Connect  Facebook";

    DLog(@"loginview subviews: %@", [loginView subviews][1]);

    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
    [loginView sizeToFit];

}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Connecting with Facebook"];
    if (! self.isFirstFBLoginDone) {
    #warning simple workaround, but not solving the source problem of twiced call from loginViewFetchedUserInfo
        if ([[SingletonClass sharedInstance] hasCredentials] == NO) {
            [self.swebapi registerUser:user];
        } else {
            [self toSurroundView];
        }

        self.isFirstFBLoginDone = TRUE;

    } // isFirstFBLoginDone
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that may be causing problems in your code --

1. Set the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegate in order to force the recognition of multiple gesture recognizers, specifically the simultaneous recognition of this new gesture recognizer alongside the Facebook login button's gesture recognizer) using: `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`
2. Set your `UIGestureRecognizer`'s `cancelsTouchesInView` property to NO.
3. Instead of initializing your the pointer to the `fbButton` as a `UIView`, you should declare `fbButton` as a `FBLoginView` and cast the `UIView` into a `FBLoginView`.
4. (Most importantly) You're adding the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view when you should be adding it to the button.

Change:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

to:

```
[fbButton addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

Comment: Hi. Updated my code with your suggestion (have a look at my question, `addTapFinder2`). It still does not recognize the tap. I am thinking of trying with a touch gesture instead of a touch gesture...

Comment: Finally got it to work. Had to add `tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` Found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16885076/1933185. Would be great if you update your answer with this information :) That other can benefit from it. *Note: replaced addTapFinder2 with addTapFinder*

Comment: Worked with ```tapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;```, thanks to jerik