# FBLoginView text only english

Tags: objective-c, xcode, localization, facebook-login

I want to localize the FBLoginView text. I searched and I don´t find how can I solved it. I implement it under objective-c (xcode). I declare it as IBOutlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize FBLoginVIew?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280850/how-to-customize-fbloginview)

Comment: No it is not the same question

Answer (score 2):

[Localizing Facebook Strings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#localize)

> The SDK installer includes a FacebookSDK.strings file that is a localizable as described in Apple's localization guide. You can include the file in your app and localize it like a typical strings file.

I took ShareIt sample from FB sdk and added `FacebookSDKStrings.bundle` in the project and changed the language of the simulator and it works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Should i copy paste the content of FacebookSKD.strings on my localizable.strings or should i try something others ?

Comment: Just drag and drop the bundle in the project and check the `Copy items` checkbox

Comment: In your Example you don´t localize the other text ? only FB Buttons are localized?

Comment: Can you try this [this ShareIt sample](http://www.4shared.com/zip/__2hmtoEce/ShareIt.html)

Comment: Yes, I didn't use localization