# Facebook IOS SDK Login Button Force Small Text

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

Is there a way to force the Facebook Login Button so it displays "Log in" as opposed to "Log in with Facebook"? Below is what it looks like on an iPhone 6

[image]

And below on an iPhone 6 Plus

[image]

I have briefly looked at the Facebook SDK on Github and have failed to come up with a solution. Facebook basically looks at the width of the button then displays the appropriate text. I don't want the text to overrun like it is on the iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: You can use Custom button instead of Facebook's default button. look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280850/how-to-customize-fbloginview

Answer (score 8):

There's actually a very easy way to customize the text of a FBSDKLoginButton.  Here you go:

```
var fbButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
var titleText = NSAttributedString(string: "Your new button title")
fbButton.setAttributedTitle(titleText, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Facebook docs:

> Localizing Facebook Strings
>
> The SDK installer includes a FacebookSDK.strings file that is a
>   localizable as described in Apple's localization guide. You can
>   include the file in your app and localize it like a typical strings
>   file.

You can copy the FacebookSDK.strings file located in the resources directory of the downloaded Facebook sdk and paste it in your project directory. The default string for the key: `LoginButton.LogInLong` is `Log in with Facebook`, you can change the string to whatever you like.